# how to write a macro in access 2010 to import data of excel sheet to access 2010 table?

Tags: ms-access-2010, import-from-excel

I want to write the Code which imports data from an excel table to a access table on a button click presents in a form.Because I am new in MS Access programming so pls explain answer briefly.

**Edit:-**

One thing i forgot to write that i am using webform not a simple form.At one forum i find that import can be achieve by using TransferSpreadSheet macro but i didn't get it in access 2010 macro commands.

Please give me some direction so that i can solve my problem.
Thanx in advance.

---

I have written the below code in my module

```
Private Sub ImportButton_Click()
  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "imported data",    "C:\Documents and Settings\himanshu\Desktop\Sales Report1.xls", True
End Sub
```

however when i click on button nothing happend. Is there anything i  am mising?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff844793.aspx). So, in VBA you would have Sub or Function with a line something like this in it:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "MyTable", "c:\MyExcelFile.xls", True
```

If you prefer to use a macro you can do something similar using the `TransferSpreadsheet` Action. But using VBA will give you more flexibility over using a macro.

Comment: @himanshu mentions "presents it in a form". I think it would be best to build the form first, and set the record source in VBA to "MyTable" , if that is what the imported table is to be called, or better still, the name of a query.